# Bring another window to the foreground via a program

Tags: c#, dll, foreach

I have a C# WindowsForms program and use it to open a PDF in the Edge browser. Unfortunately, Edge opens in the background; how do I get it in the foreground?

This is what I tried, what I found on the internet, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path);
    p.Start();

    foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (pr.MainWindowTitle != "")
        {
            if (pr.MainWindowTitle.ToString().Contains("Microsoft Edge"))
            {
                IntPtr Handle = pr.MainWindowHandle;

                SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the opposite, your program goes to the background, might be slightly easier.